# program execution never stops while writing to files using FileOutputStream in java

Tags: java, file, java-8

this is the code for creating configure file if it does not exist.
while executing, file is created and contents are successfully written in the file. But program execution never stops

```
FileOutputStream obj = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(obj);    
Writer input = new BufferedWriter(osw);
input.write("autoupdate = false\n");
input.write("autoscan = false");
input.close();
```

Comment: `BufferedWriter#close()` is not documented to close the underlying stream... please "try to" close `obj` and `osw` as well!

Comment: BufferedWriter certain _does_ close the underlying stream @xerx593.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you saying that the program hangs in the lines that you  have posted?  I find it hard to believe unless you are writing to some file-system where the underlying native writes are hanging.

Comment: Why are you naming an output object `input`? Don't do that. It only confuses people, starting with yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be some with Windows? You didn't specify your OS.
Try with FileWriter.

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    writer.write("autoupdate = false\n");
    writer.write("autoscan = false");
}
```

Comment: Try it why? Or are you just guessing?

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by **"program execution never stops"**? You're obviously not showing everything here. What is suppose to stop program execution in your application? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Other than a couple little quirks I don't see how your code is suppose infinitely maintain program execution, but hey, I'm old and can't see well anymore.

If you're using Java 7 or newer, utilizing the [Try-with-Resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) would be beneficial since it will auto close everything for you. Here is an example:

```
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("ConfigFile.conf"), "UTF-8"))) {
    writer.write("autoupdate = false" + System.lineSeparator());
    writer.write("autoscan = false" + System.lineSeparator());
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 'Not closing your outer stream'? What do you think `input.close()` does exactly?

Comment: Create a bigger brain fart than has already been exhausted. Corrected, thank you.